# How to prepare APN for production

Tags: ios, node.js, apple-push-notifications

Im trying to deploy my app with notifications but it's giving me the biggest headache in the world. All other questions ive seen with regards to this seem outdated.

I set up APNs to be sent from a nodeJS script that I have running. When running in my sandbox everything was working well. As soon as I sent my app to TestFlight, notifications stopped sending. My script is still Successfully sending to the Notification Id registered with my phone but im assuming its not the correct production Id. If anyone canhelp get me sending production notifications it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

[image: Submited build settings]

[image: Provisioning profile]

APN Server code

```
 var options = {
token: {
key: "AuthKey_6V27D43P5R.p8",
keyId: "3Z6SEF7GE5",
teamId: "ASQJ3L7765"
},

    production: true
};
var apnProvider = new apn.Provider(options);

function SendIOSNotification(token, message, sound, payload, badge){
var deviceToken = token; //phone notification id
var notification = new apn.Notification(); //prepare notif
notification.topic = 'com.GL.Greek-Life'; // Specify your iOS app's Bundle ID (accessible within the project editor)
notification.expiry = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600; // Set expiration to 1 hour from now (in case device is offline)
notification.badge = badge; //selected badge
notification.sound = sound; //sound is configurable
notification.alert = message; //supports emoticon codes
notification.payload = {id: payload}; // Send any extra payload data with the notification which will be accessible to your app in didReceiveRemoteNotification
    apnProvider.send(notification, deviceToken).then(function(result) {  //send actual notifcation
    // Check the result for any failed devices

    var subToken = token.substring(0, 6);
    console.log("Succesfully sent message to ", subToken);
    }).catch( function (error) {
            console.log("Faled to send message to ", subToken);
    })
}
```

Comment: have you created APNS certificate for production type and set its respective pem/p12 file at server side?

Comment: There are different certificates for Dev and Production for APNS. You have to create the production one and then it will work. Please paste the error so we can see exactly what you're facing.

Comment: If you use the new https push service then the same certificate works for the sandbox and production. Have you set the environment variable to tell your node.js script to use the production push server?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the help. To answer each of you:
Van im not sure how to set the pem/p12 files in nodeJS?
AbhyuditJain I created the production one using a .p8 file. There is no error, the apn is successfully sending but the phone doesnt receive it

Paulw11 yes as you can see in the code, production: true